# Pandas slicing strings: keep all characters up to the second full stop and create new column to hold the new value

Tags: python, pandas, string, slice

I need to slice the strings in a particular column and create a new column with the slice in it.
i.e. existing col A: 'CODE.45.6787' used to create col B: 'CODE.45'
Thank you!

Comment: Is the value of column A always the same format? If so, you can use: `df['new_col'] = df.A.str[:7]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be generic, I won't assume your strings all have only 2 full stops.  Hence, I will not split your strings from the right and will instead maintain on splitting the strings from the left.  For this, we can do it as follows:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.split('.').str[0:2].str.join('.')
```

### Demo

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['CODE.45.6787', 'CODE.12.3456.78']})

df['B'] = df['A'].str.split('.').str[0:2].str.join('.')


print(df)

                 A        B
0     CODE.45.6787  CODE.45
1  CODE.12.3456.78  CODE.12
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
df["B"] = df["A"].str.rsplit(".", 1).str[0]
print(df)

              A        B
0  CODE.45.6787  CODE.45
```